# grep: match pattern on a particular position

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I need to match a pattern with `grep`, only if it starts at position 16. Let's suppose I want to match the string `' pattern'` (starting with space).

The following should match

```
bla bla bla bla pattern
```

whereas following should not match, because the search pattern does not start at pos. 16:

```
bla bla bla bla foo foo pattern
```

I have tried using this regular expression

```
egrep '.*\{15\} pattern'
```

but this does not seem to work as desired.

Can somebody please suggest a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by _position_? Does a TAB character count as one position. What about multi-byte characters?

Comment: You do not need to escape the metacharacters `( )` and `{ }` in extended regular expressions.  You are using `egrep` so by escaping those you are matching literal `{` and `}`.  Don't escape those and your regex would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
grep -E '^.{15} pattern'
```

This will be fine in most usage cases. However note that it won't 'match' just the `pattern` part, but everything before it will be included in the match too. You will see this by the highlighting of `grep` (if `--color` is given directly or has been included in a shell alias). Without colour, it will affect `grep -o` which prints just the matched part. Eg:

```
$ echo 'bla bla bla bla pattern' | grep -Eo '^.{15}( pattern)'
bla bla bla bla pattern
```

To avoid this with GNU grep, you can use a perl expression with look behind. Eg:

```
$ echo 'bla bla bla bla pattern' | grep -Po '(?<=^.{15}) pattern'
 pattern
```

This 'matches' the `pattern` part only.